# Transpiling es6 modules to run in the browser

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a simple example of an app where I am using es6 modules, and I want to transpile them down to es5 (I don't want to run modules in the browser, although I am aware their support is 90%+ at this point).

I am going round in circles coming up against the same errors and problems.
Here is my setup and what I am trying to achieve:

```
//add.js
export function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

//multiply.js
export function multiply(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}
```

Then I run babel to output a `bundle.js` file using the `@babel/preset-env` preset.

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.add = add;

function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.multiply = multiply;

function multiply(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}
```

When I run my `html` file in the browser, the console logs the following error:
`bundle.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

My question is this:
**What is babel outputting?

Are they commonjs modules?

How can I get es6 modules to run in the browser?**

Comment: **1)** Please include your babel configuration. **2)** The browser is throwing the error because `exports` is never declared, and this is an error under `"use strict";` rules.

Comment: I was in your shoes a number of months ago, then I discovered rollup (allowing me to remove webpack and Babel direct dependencies entirely). It’s less featured, but very lightweight, and offers a bunch of plugins. Sounds like the ‘umd’ build is what you’re after.

Comment: @TheJim01 - I have now included my ```.babelrc``` config file. Are you saying that the use strict setting is responsible solely for this error? I am not sure this is correct, when I manually remove ```'use strict'``` the same error remains

Comment: Yes, those look like CommonJS modules.

Comment: Rather than manually removing `"use strict";`, instead try adding `var exports = {};` as the second line of the bundle file. **This is not a solution,** but that change should make it work.

Comment: @TheJim01 - thanks for that, I have tried that already and got it working. I am looking to get this into production at some point, but if you're saying that's not a solution, what would you recommend (I felt it was quite hacky)? I guess that's why I posted the question originally, I wanted to open up a discussion

Comment: @ne1410s - Thanks. I was actually already using rollup for something, but I wasn't aware umd's were what I wanted. This is allows me to output the files and access the functions from within my html page - I don't know if this is the best way I could have done it, but maybe there is no best way, this at least looks promising. I have upvoted. Thank you

Comment: "esmodules": true" is wrong, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

`"esmodules": true"` is wrong.

when specifying `"esmodules": true"`, browsers targets will be ignored and scripts not transpiled to es5. the output depends on your `target` values. modern browsers handle es6 modules native, the best way is to transpile modern browsers different then legacy browser (ie11) and load scripts specific e.g

```
// low transpiled (loads only in modern browser)
<script type="module" src="/assets/scripts/main.js"></script>

// full transpiled (loads only in legacy browser) --> polyfill this bundle
<script nomodule src="/assets/scripts/main.legacy.js" defer></script>
```

```
// https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/settings/javascript/babel-config.js
const modern = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      // define transpile level
      targets: {
        browsers: [
          "> 1% in EU",
          "not ie 11",
          "not dead"
        ]
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 3,
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-eval"
  ],
  comments: false,
  cacheDirectory: path.join(CACHE_PATH, 'babel-loader')
};

const legacy = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      // define transpile level
      targets: {
        browsers: [
          "> 1% in CH",
          "ie >= 11",
          "not dead"
        ]
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 3,
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-eval"
  ],
  comments: false,
  cacheDirectory: path.join(CACHE_PATH, 'babel-loader')
};
```

Please check the [babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @tfr. I understand you can use a fall back from nomodule browsers, but i guess the overall question would be how to polyfill esmodules for the old browsers. If I did that, i wouldn't need to have a module nomodule pattern.
Also, i have gone round in circles trying different options. esmodules: false didn't seem to change any output

Comment: esmodules: false and add target is the right answer here. how to polyfill is another topic